# Expect commands on SSH going out of sync

Tags: unix, ssh, expect

I created a script where i need to run few commands on a remote terminal using SSH. So i used expect statements but the problem is, suppose i have to run 5 statements on remote terminal then out of 6 times, around 3-4 times, those 5 commands go out of sync i.e. command are not getting executed in the correct sequence and not in proper manner i.e. firstly 1st command should complete and then second should run. 
I tried to set timeout 5 or even 10 but it didn't help. I tried sleep 2 or 4 even but it also didn't help. Here is the script i created along with output. Please help me. Thanks.

Script:

```
do some work on current shell
#echo $name 
## ssh part of script starts

/usr/bin/expect<<EXEOF

set timeout -1
match_max 100000
spawn ssh "myuser\@IP_ADDRESS"
expect "*assword:*"
send -- "mypassword\r"
send -- "\r"
#expect -re "(%|*>|#|\\$)"
expect "*>"
#expect "*OFR:offline-ure>"   #actual prompt of ssh terminal
send -- "\r"
set timeout 20
#sleep 1
send -- "tcsh\r"
send -- "\r"
set timeout 2
expect -re "(%|>|#|\\$)"
#set timeout 10
send -- "cd /home/myuser/cap/\r"
send -- "\r"
set timeout 4
expect -re "(%|>|#|\\$)"
send -- "source cap.env\r"
send -- "\r"
set timeout 10
send -- "cd /home/myuser/bin/\r"
set timeout 5
expect -re "(%|>|#|\\$)"
send -- "$myCommand\r"
#set timeout 50
#sleep 40
send -- "exit\r"
expect -re "(%|>|#|\\$)"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof

EXEOF
echo "end of ssh script"
some task after ssh part of script
```

**When i run it, i see below output:**

```
spawn ssh myuser@IP_ADDRESS
myuser@XX.XX.XX.XXX's password:
Last login: Tue Mar 10 07:56:19 2015 from XX.XX.XX.XX

OFR:offline-ure> tcsh   (see here all commands are sent together)

source ccap.env

cd /home/myuser/bin/
mycommand_String_value
exit
exit
[sncpuser@offline-ure ~]$
[sncpuser@offline-ure ~]$ source ccap.env
ccap.env: No such file or directory.
[sncpuser@offline-ure ~]$
[sncpuser@offline-ure ~]$ cd /home/myuser/bin/
[sncpuser@offline-ure bin]$ mycommand_string_value
some output of my command
[sncpuser@offline-ure bin]$ exit
exit
OFR:offline-ure>
OFR:offline-ure> cd /home/myuser/cap/     (this was second command)
OFR:offline-ure> exit
Connection to xx.xx.xx.xxx closed.
end of ssh script
```

Please note in output, all commands that i need to execute of SSH terminal are sent at same time and hence does not run properly and in correct sequence.
Please suggest how can i resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` to the top of your expect script and expect will tell you when your expect patterns don't match (or match unexpectedly)

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, else it would have been one, but you appear to be making life difficult for yourself. `expect` scripts are error prone, so you want to reduce them to the minimum possible.

Why not:

```
ssh foo ". /home/myusr/cap/env ; /home/myusr/cap/bin/cmd"
```

And just use `expect` to do the username / password bit?

Or better, use public key authentication and don't do username / passwords at all, and drop `expect` entirely?

You asked in the comments how to pass multiple commands to `ssh`. Try this:

```
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so$ ssh 192.200.0.1 'pwd ; ls | wc -l ; cd .. ; pwd ; ls | wc -l'
amb@192.200.0.1's password:
/home/amb
132
/home
2
```

`ssh` will by default use your login shell. If you really need use `tcsh` and that's not your login shell, here's one way to do it:

```
ssh 192.200.0.1 '/bin/sh -c "pwd ; ls | wc -l ; cd .. ; pwd ; ls | wc -l"'
```

An alternative would be to put a script file on the remote system, e.g. in `/home/myuser/cap/bin/dostuff` write:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
cd /home/myuser/cap/
source cap.env
cd /home/myuser/bin/
# next line will run the file given as the first parameter
$1
exit
```

Then invoke it as:

```
ssh 192.200.0.1 /home/myuser/cap/bin/dostuff /path/to/file/to/run
```

I suspect the actual problem is to do with allocation of pseudoterminals. You may want to play with the `-t` and `-T` options to `ssh`.

Comment: Thanks abligh for such a quick response. I am a bit new to these things but i need to use username/password thing.
How to use this:
ssh foo ". /home/myusr/cap/env ; /home/myusr/cap/bin/cmd"

means once i have done SSH, i need to execute around 5 commands in sequence . So how can use the code you suggested. Can you help a little more here. I dont know how to use expect for username/password only and then run command normally or remote terminal....

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the delay at the input buffer. I guess you can try this before using `send`.

```
set send_slow {10  .001}
send -s "password\r"
```